# Can i run an Asp.Net core angular app inside a Wpf app

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, .net-core

We have a WPF app running and we're in the process of writing a web-based mirror of the application with Angular. Currently we have it setup like so;

- MyApp.csproj    netfx 4.8, Wpf
- MyWebApp.csproj netcore 3.1, asp .net core

  - /ClientApps Angular latest

Currently we run both MyApp.exe (main gui application) and MyWebApp.exe (asp net core webserver). MyWebApp communicates with MyApp over SignalR. The angular browser apps then communicate with MyWebApp over signalR and some HTTP.

I'm exploring the following option:

- Upgrade MyApp to netcore
- I hope WPF and netcore are fully compatible by now..
- Then remove the webserver and angular apps from MyWebApp and move it into MyApp
- Then completely remove MyWebApp as it now lives in MyApp.

My question is, would this be possible? Can i call `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder..` from somewhere in MyApp?

Additionaly i welcome any suggestions/remarks on whether this idea would be smart or not. For example, Wpf and Asp handle threads and the threadpool differently. I reckon i won't encounter problems there but if you think otherwise, please let me know.

Comment: You're migrating from angular to wpf? Host your web pages on a server. Display in the wpf app in a webview2. Which i think is still in preview.

Comment: @Andy Hi! no. We currently have a WPF app, and we're rebuilding that app in angular. So the WPF app and the angular app will both be in use. Right now i host the angular app with an asp.net core server, and i'm wondering if i can put that inside my WPF app (cause that's where all the data lives)

Comment: There are hosting options which don't involve iis. My advice would be to stick with a regular web server. Upgrading to net core can be simple for some apps.  Trickier for others. You start by editing csproj to the new format. Change nuget packages to net core or net standard dependent ones. Interactivity has moved to nuget behaviors eg. Then fix anything that broke. In complex apps you need to fully regression test because there are some subtle differences between net old and net core.  It just depends on the app as to how much work a conversion is.

Comment: @Andy Right now i use kestrel (built-in) with asp.net core app. But if i see your response 'My advice would be to stick with a regular web server' it seems like you don't consider my proposal a good idea which i will take with me. In terms op upgrading to net core, i think its quite possible. I already moved to the new csproj format (although that process didn't go as smooth as i hoped, but neither was it horrible or something)

Comment: I suppose it partly depends if your company totally controls standardised desktops for your users.  Maybe your environment makes it a less risky choice. Once we built our non-iis web server to run on our desktops we hit complications. My limited experience was not positive.

Comment: BTW depends how far you are down the angular route and expertise etc. Personally, I think blazor webassembly will gain substantial market share from the likes of angular. I also prefer the less opinionated nature of react to angular.

Comment: @Andy great points. Unfortunately we are too early for blazor as of now, and we chose angular at some point because the architecture was more in line with how we did things in C#, but i get your point. We're lucky that our app runs on our own computers so we're in control in that regard.